# non-parametric binomial test for clustered data

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, nonparametric, clustered-standard-errors

Consider that you want to test the performance in school between two schools. The dependent (observable) variable is whether a student passed a course or not. I want to compare proportions of students who passed courses between the two schools. There are 4 courses in total. A simple way would be to perform a proportional test over all courses between the two schools. However this test assumes independence of observations which is not the case: each student has repeated observations as he was examined in each of the 4 courses. Therefore, I need to use clustered standard errors (correct?). I am using R so suggestions in this language are greatly appreciated but commands in other languages are most welcome.

Comment: You could think of your dependent variable as binary (pass/no-pass), and use logistic regression.  You would be able to construct a relatively complex model, maybe using a mixed effects model (GLMM in R), treating perhaps students or courses as random effects.

Comment: I am already thinking my variable as 0-1. The model would not be that complicated, it would only require one explanatory variable: the school index to which I would cluster by student id. The problem is that (logistic) regression is parametric. I need a **nonparametric** test if possible.

Comment: Why do you think that logistic regression wouldn't be appropriate?

Comment: I am not saying it's not appropriate in general. But the tests that derive from that regression will be parametric right? My question was, "Is there a nonparametric way to test this?"

Comment: But why do you want nonparametrics? The only thing that rally can go wrong with binomial assumptions is independence, and when your model have taken that into account, whats the problem?